# How to use PanelSnap plugin package in angular2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular8

I was using jquery.Panelsnap plugin in static HTML pages. Now I am migrating my application to angular8. But I am unable to refer PanelSnap plugin.

```
    npm install panelsnap
```

In my app.component.ts,

```
    import { PanelSnap } from 'panelsnap/src/panelsnap';
    new PanelSnap()
```

is throwing error saying PanelSnap is undefined. I tried to create object on constructor, but no success. Also tried to refer panelsnap.js in angular.json, still no luck.

```
     "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/panelsnap/src/panelsnap.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you can find the basic setup. You should not add brackets around your import, as the module is directly exported.

```js
import PanelSnap from 'panelsnap';

const instance = new PanelSnap();
```